# Why is there a delay between webapp2.RequestHandler finishing and AppEngine actually sending the response

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post, logging

My **RequestHandler** looks like this:

```
class GetChart(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        station_id = cgi.escape(self.request.get('id'))
        request_time = cgi.escape(self.request.get('time'))
        request_date_string = cgi.escape(self.request.get('date'))
        request_date = datetime.strptime(
            request_date_string, "%m/%d/%Y")
        # Build the URL string. (Details removed.)
        url_string = ****
        logging.info(url_string)
        sock = urllib2.urlopen(url_string)
        data = sock.read()
        sock.close()
        for line in data.split('\n'):
            # If I put 'pass' here instead, there's no delay between
            # the 'Returning' and the response actually being sent.
            logging.info(line)

        result_json = {'status': 'Not implemented'}
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(result_json))
        logging.info('Returning.')

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/submit', GetChart)],
                              debug=True)
```

In my **logs**, I see this:

```
INFO     2011-11-26 19:41:44,243 atmosview.py:131] Returning.
INFO     2011-11-26 19:41:51,331 dev_appserver.py:2753] "POST /submit HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

That's a 7 second delay between the 'Returning' being logged, and the response actually being sent. Why is this?

I also notice that if I replace the `logging.info(line)` with `pass`, the delay is much less: about 0.2 seconds.

Is there something with the logging module that causes the function to not actually return immediately, especially when a lot of calls have been made to `logging.info()`?

Comment: It looks like this may be a bug in the AppEngine 1.6.0 dev_appserver: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6315

Comment: How do you know what the delay is without the log? And how do you know that the timestamp on the last log entry accurately reflects the actual time the request completed?

Comment: Are you actually experiencing a 7 second delay between request and response, or is it just a delay in the logs?

Comment: @NickJohnson I never said I removed all logging. I said that if I replace the `logging.info(line)` with `pass`, then the delay between the two log lines I've shown ('Returning', and 'POST...') is much less, about 0.2 seconds.

Comment: @DrewSears The delay is not just in the logs. The response isn't sent for about 7 seconds after the 'Returning' is logged. It's sent when the dev_appserver.py logs the "POST..." message. The web client waiting for the response has behaviour consistent with this diagnosis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this may be a bug in the AppEngine 1.6.0 dev_appserver: code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6315